# Replacement for dataframe.iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'am working on a script for migrating data from MongoDB to Clickhouse. Because of the reason that nested structures are'nt implemented good enough in Clickhouse, I iterate over nested structure and bring them to flat representation, where every element of nested structure is a distinct row in Clickhouse database.

What I do is iterate over list of dictionaries and take target values. The structure looks like this:

```
[
 {
  'Comment': None,
  'Details': None,
  'FunnelId': 'MegafonCompany',
  'IsHot': False,
  'IsReadonly': False,
  'Name': 'Новый',
  'SetAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 20, 10, 39, 55, 475000),
  'SetById': 'ekaterina.karpenko',
  'SetByName': 'Екатерина Карпенко',
  'Stage': {
            'Label': 'Новые',
            'Order': 0,
            '_id': 'newStage'
           },
  'Tags': None,
  'Type': 'Unknown',
  'Weight': 120,
  '_id': 'new'
 },
 {
  'Comment': None,
  'Details': {
              'Name': 'взят в работу', 
              '_id': 1
             },
  'FunnelId': 'MegafonCompany',
  'IsHot': False,
  'IsReadonly': False,
  'Name': 'В работе',
  'SetAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 20, 10, 40, 4, 841000),
  'SetById': 'ekaterina.karpenko',
  'SetByName': 'Екатерина Карпенко',
  'Stage': {
            'Label': 'Приглашение на интервью',
            'Order': 1,
            '_id': 'recruiterStage'
           },
  'Tags': None,
  'Type': 'InProgress',
  'Weight': 80,
  '_id': 'phoneInterview'
 }
]
```

I have a function that does this on dataframe object via data.iterrows() method:

```
def to_flat(data, coldict, field_last_upd):

m_status_history = stc.special_mongo_names['status_history_cand']
n_statuse_change = coldict['n_statuse_change']['name']

data[n_statuse_change] = n_status_change(dp.force_take_series(data, m_status_history))
flat_cols = [ x for x in coldict.values() if x['coltype'] == stc.COLTYPE_FLAT ]
old_cols_names = [ x['name'] for x in coldict.values() if x['coltype'] == stc.COLTYPE_PREPARATION ]
t_time = time.time()
t_len = 0
new_rows = list()

    for j in range(row[n_statuse_change]):
        t_new_value_row = np.empty(shape=[0, 0])
        for k in range(len(flat_cols)):
            if flat_cols[k]['colsubtype'] == stc.COLSUBTYPE_FLATPATH:
                new_value = dp.under_value_line(
                    row,
                    path_for_status(j, row[n_statuse_change]-1, flat_cols[k]['path'])
                )
                # Дополнительно обрабатываем дату
                if flat_cols[k]['name'] == coldict['status_set_at']['name']:
                    new_value = dp.iso_date_to_datetime(new_value)

                if flat_cols[k]['name'] == coldict['status_set_at_mil']['name']:
                    new_value = dp.iso_date_to_miliseconds(new_value)

                if flat_cols[k]['name'] == coldict['status_stage_order']['name']:
                    try:
                        new_value = int(new_value)
                    except:
                        new_value = new_value
            else:
                if flat_cols[k]['name'] == coldict['status_index']['name']:
                    new_value = j

            t_new_value_row = np.append(t_new_value_row, dp.some_to_null(new_value))
        new_rows.append(np.append(row[old_cols_names].values, t_new_value_row))
pdb.set_trace()
res = pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns = [
    x['name'] for x in coldict.values() if x['coltype'] == stc.COLTYPE_FLAT or x['coltype'] == stc.COLTYPE_PREPARATION
])

return res
```

It takes values from list of dicts, prepare them to correspond Clickhouse's requirements using numpy arrays and then appends them all together to get new dataframe with targeted values and its columnnames.

I've noticed that if nested structure is big enough, it begins to work much slower. I've found an article where different methods of iteration in Python are compared. [article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

It is claimed that it's much faster to iterate over .apply() method and even faster using vectorization. But the samples given are pretty trivial and rely on using the same function on all of the values. Is it possible to iterate over pandas object in faster manner, while using variety of functions on different types of data?

Answer (score 0):

I think your first step should be converting your data into a pandas dataframe, then it will be so much easier to handle it. I couldn't deschiper the exact functions you wanted to run, but perhaps my example helps

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

data_dict_array = [
 {
  'Comment': None,
  'Details': None,
  'FunnelId': 'MegafonCompany',
  'IsHot': False,
  'IsReadonly': False,
  'Name': 'Новый',
  'SetAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 20, 10, 39, 55, 475000),
  'SetById': 'ekaterina.karpenko',
  'SetByName': 'Екатерина Карпенко',
  'Stage': {
            'Label': 'Новые',
            'Order': 0,
            '_id': 'newStage'
           },
  'Tags': None,
  'Type': 'Unknown',
  'Weight': 120,
  '_id': 'new'
 },
 {
  'Comment': None,
  'Details': {
              'Name': 'взят в работу', 
              '_id': 1
             },
  'FunnelId': 'MegafonCompany',
  'IsHot': False,
  'IsReadonly': False,
  'Name': 'В работе',
  'SetAt': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 20, 10, 40, 4, 841000),
  'SetById': 'ekaterina.karpenko',
  'SetByName': 'Екатерина Карпенко',
  'Stage': {
            'Label': 'Приглашение на интервью',
            'Order': 1,
            '_id': 'recruiterStage'
           },
  'Tags': None,
  'Type': 'InProgress',
  'Weight': 80,
  '_id': 'phoneInterview'
 }
]

#converting your data into something pandas can read
# in particular, flattening the stage dict
for data_dict in data_dict_array:
    d_temp = data_dict.pop("Stage")
    data_dict["Stage_Label"] = d_temp["Label"]
    data_dict["Stage_Order"] = d_temp["Order"]
    data_dict["Stage_id"] = d_temp["_id"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict_array)

# lets say i want to set comment to "cool" if name is 'В работе'
# in .loc[], the first argument is filtering the rows, the second argument is picking the column
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'В работе','Comment'] = "cool"
df
```